# tuples are inmutable, create lists before replacing its entries

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I was trying to do some simple manipulation of lists and numpy arrays and got stuck in some easy thing:

```
a=np.arange(12)
a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
a=np.reshape(a,(3,4))
a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

b=np.arange(12,24)
b
array([12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
b=np.reshape(3,4)
list1 = [(a,'a'),(b,'b')]
data = [(i, j) for i,j in list1]
```

When I tried to do:

```
data[0][0]=np.delete(data[0][0], np.s_[-1::],0)
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

But if I do:

```
cop=np.delete(data[0][0], np.s_[-1::],0)
cop
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

It works perfectly fine.

But I also can't do:

```
data[0][0]=np.copy(cop)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

But if I check the types, both are actually arrays:

```
type(cop)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

type(data[0][0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I couldn’t find the mistake for quite a few hours.

Comment: FWIW -- I don't think this is a bad question.  It states the problem with code which can be used to reproduce the problem.  A traceback is posted.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I realized that data is actually a tuple.

So this is what solves the problem:

```
data = [[i, j] for i,j in list1]
```

And then I can replace elements like data[0][0]

Comment: You can accept your own answer, although you won't get any reputation, it shows that this question has been answered successfully.

Comment: @paddila -- I believe that SO requires that you want 24 hours before accepting your own solution.

Comment: Oops, typo.  That should have been SO makes you *wait* 24 hrs, not *want* :).